# Counting certain cubes with bicolor vertices

Tags: combinatorics

We can count the number of squares with vertices colored blue or red, excluding those with one diagonal blue and one diagonal red, and get easily $16-2=14$.

The number of cubes with vertices red or blue, and without any rectangle (not only the faces) formed by four vertices such that one diagonal is blue and the other one is red, can be enumerated with a brute force program and is $104$.

To be clear, the orientation of the cube matters, i.e. two cubes that are equal up to rotation and reflection are considered distinct and counted as two.

**Question:**

Any idea to get the result in some systematic way like inclusion-exclusion or other method?
Do you think it might be possible in the first place?

**Some background:**

I have posted (copied from others) a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/462613/136218) regarding a conjecture: the hypercubes with the property above are the same as linearly separable boolean functions, counted by [OEIS A000609](https://oeis.org/A000609).
If the conjecture is true (most likely it is) and if we have a method to count hypercubes with the above property, then there is a way to get a formula or at least more terms for A000609. For this reason it might be difficult to get, although the conjecture could be still "unknown". Hope not to discourage possible answers with that.